# Arranging multiple outputs from forEach function into one array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the `hrefs` from the `li` elements with javascript. My function looks like this:

```
function checkUrl() {
    checkUrl = function(){};
    function hrefHome() {
        var listCont = document.querySelectorAll(".wpcm-listings-item");
        listCont.forEach(Children);
        function Children(item) {
            var Child = item.children;
            var Hrefs = Child[0].href;
            console.log(Hrefs);
        }
    }
}
```

This is returning my `hrefs` like I want it to, but now I need to put all of them in `localStorage`. I tried adding `localStorage.vehHrefs = Hrefs;` after the variable Hrefs, but the second one overwrites the first. What I want to do is create an array of all the `hrefs` and then put the array in `localStorage` but I need some help. Below is my HTML.

```
<div class="wpcm-vehicle-results-wrapper">
    <ul class="wpcm-vehicle-results">
        <li class="wpcm-listings-item wpcm-listings-item-featured">
            <a href="http://localhost/sr19repairables/vehicle/asdfasdf/">
                <div class="wpcm-listings-item-image-wrapper">
                    <img src="Chevy.jpg" class="wp-post-image" onload="checkUrl()"
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wpcm-listings-item wpcm-listings-item-featured">
            <a href="http://localhost/sr19repairables/vehicles/repairables/2020-gmc-sierra/">
                <div class="wpcm-listings-item-image-wrapper">
                    <img src="Chevy1.jpg" class="wp-post-image" onload="checkUrl()">
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should use map rather than forEach:

```
function checkUrl() {
  checkUrl = function () {};
  function hrefHome() {
    var listCont = document.querySelectorAll('.wpcm-listings-item');
    var hrefs = [...listCont].map(function Children(item) {
      var Child = item.children;
      return Child[0].href;
    });
    console.log(hrefs);
    // To add it to localstorage:
    localStorage.setItem('key',JSON.stringify(hrefs));
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I kept getting the error that Child wasn't defined. I tried everything I could think of but nothing worked.

Comment: I just double checked and NodeLists, which is what is returned from querySelectorAll, doesn't have maps. I've updated my answer and it should now work since I'm using iterables to make it a real array rather than just array-like.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I like this idea better, it's easier to read and it's less code. One question: Why doesn't putting brackets (```[ ]```) around the ```document.querySelectorAll``` work? I tried that before you updated your answer and it didn't work.

Comment: I put in [ ...listCont ] because the listCont works as an iterator and allows the array spread operator (...) to spread the values in listCont out into the array I create.
If you use [listCont] without the spread operator, then it would be an array with a single element of the NodeList from the querySelectorAll function.

Comment: Here's Mozilla on the spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax and iterators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function checkUrl() {
checkUrl = function(){};
function hrefHome() {
    var listCont = document.querySelectorAll(".wpcm-listings-item");
    var HrefArr = [];
    listCont.forEach(Children);
    localStorage.vehHrefs = JSON.stringify(HrefArr);
    function Children(item) {
        var Child = item.children;
        var Hrefs = Child[0].href;
        HrefArr.push(Href)
        console.log(Hrefs);
    }
}
```

}